# Use Password Protected Form without the use of wp-login.php

Tags: wp-admin, password, wp-login-form

I need to password protect a page, but from what I looked up -- the action of the form needs to use something like this:

`action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '"`

OR

`action="' . get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-login.php?action=postpass"`

which both are the exact same thing and both utilizes the `wp-login.php`.

The problem I am facing is that my company uses a VPN to allow access to the `/wp-admin` login page -- which in turn also affects the `wp-login.php` file. Because of this, the password protected page effect does not work for our users due to the VPN constraint and routes them to a 403 status page. Is there an alternative way to use the password protected page functionality without the action requiring the use of `wp-login.php` ?

I assume not, but though to ask if anyone had any insights. Whitelisting on the VPN would defeat the purpose of our use of a VPN to access the admin panel as well, so sorta stuck in a dilemma.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisV do not post comments as the solution to the question. It does not matter if you can or can't post comments, do not spam the site

Comment: As for the question, the normal solution is to fix the VPN requirement to add an exception for when the action is postpass

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could try

1. Use a plugin like [Rename wp-login.php](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/) and change what the VPN points to from `wp-login.php` to whatever you rename it
2. Use plugin to handle the post password protection. I haven't tried any, but there should be one out there that works without relying on `wp-login.php`. A few that came up when searching are [Password Protect Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/password-protect-page/) and [Passster](https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-protector/). The native way post passwords works is pretty rubbish so it wouldn't be a bad idea to change it

Comment: If the company wants a VPN to allow access to the login/wp-admin then redirecting it so that it doesn’t is counter-productive to what someone specifically wanted and set-up.